# Custom image name on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm developing an iPhone application, which has similar functionality to Camera Roll. In full size mode (e.g. viewing selected image in full size), I want to display the picture name (image file name).

The problem here: If the user changes the picture name on their PC and upload the picture back to their iPhone, I'm still getting original file name (e.g. "IMG_xxx), while I would like to get the name given by user. If I go to MyPictures on my iPhone, I do see user custom names.

How I can get a custom image name?

Thanks!

Comment: could you paste some code (especially part with setting file names)?

Answer (score 0):

simple answer is No. You cannot do what are requesting.

In your app you can call an image whatever you want but once you save it to iPhone/iPad camera roll then it is renamed automatically by iOS. We developers have no control over that behavior.

Now if you were to save that picture in your apps document dir and some how let the user download / upload those pics using iTunes file sharing then perhaps that may work for you.

Comment: No way to access the file name through the imagePicker's delegate?

Comment: @Sam Budda - but how you explain that after saving back image with changed file name, this new file name appears on iPhone? (this is what I see when opening image from "Pictures")

Comment: "this new file name appears on iPhone?" ... this is not how it works. I have tested this with multiple camera apps that I have created over the years.